# Count on multiple columns using different Where clause

Tags: sql, count, insert, multiple-columns

I would greatly appreciate some assistance creating a query that performs a count on multiple columns and then inserts the data into a new table. There is a table that stores grades for each student based on Marking period. I have written a query to calculate the number of D's or F's a student received for Mark 1. Now I want to run the same calculation for Mark 2. Here is what I have for the Mark 1 code:

```
SELECT STU.ID, COUNT(GRD.M1) as DF_M1
INTO LCAPDEMO 
FROM STU JOIN
    GRD ON STU.SN = GRD.SN AND STU.SC = GRD.SC
WHERE GRD.M1 IN ('D+','D','D-','F+','F','F-')
GROUP BY STU.ID
```

This process needs to be run each night for both Mark 1 and Mark 2 grades.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want conditional aggregation?

```
SELECT STU.ID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN GRD.M1 IN ('D+', 'D', 'D-', 'F+', 'F', 'F-')
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as DF_M1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN GRD.M2 IN ('D+', 'D', 'D-', 'F+', 'F', 'F-')
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as DF_M2
INTO LCAPDEMO 
FROM STU JOIN
     GRD
     ON STU.SN = GRD.SN AND STU.SC = GRD.SC
GROUP BY STU.ID;
```

Comment: I do, but it was built in already. Just left it off the question to help simplify. This works perfectly. Thank you for your time.